# Any Easy Solution to the Hands of Time Clock Puzzles?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

In the temporal rifts that lead to mini-games, is there any easy solution or useful tricks to solving the clock puzzles? In general I resort to randomly choosing a few options and hoping they work out. I wanted to play an RPG - not Super Magic Happy Clocks, but I disgress...

I understand the basic concepts and I realize that each puzzle is randomly generated so there aren't pre-determined solutions. Any tips / advice is greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few hands of time solvers out there.

Personally i find these the best:

http://clockpuzzle.pl/ (its online so nothing to download)

or

http://www.mediafire.com/?dar4yh69lxcaavh

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! This was such a time- and frustration-saver!! The first link works in most mobile devices (including tablets) which is very convenient. You want to enter the number in the "12 o'clock" position first and work your way clock-wise. The resulting diagram is very easy to follow. The first move to make is the highlighted number in the diagram.

Answer (score 4):

Doing it manually, I've found the best way to get a correct solution is to look at each number on the board, and mark which numbers it can be the next in the chain. Rather than continue the chain, I move onto the next number clockwise, until I've built a table of values. That table is usually enough to figure out the correct chain.

So, for example, take the following clock:

```
  2
2   2
3   1
  1
```

Assigning a letter to each number starting with the 2 at the top and working my way clockwise, I can generate a table like this:

```
    A | B | C | D | E | F
--------------------------
A   x | x | o | x | o | x
B   o | x | o | x | x | x
C   x | o | x | o | x | x
D   x | o | x | x | x | o
E   x | o | x | x | x | x
F   x | o | x | o | x | x
```

From this, I can see that *E* must lead into *B*. By eliminating other choices as they become locked in the chain, I can arrive at the correct solution, which is:

> *A* → *E* → *B* → *C* → *D* → *F*

This scales to any size clock, but it's tedious. So instead, I decided to write an automated solution in PHP:

```
<?php

// Supply clock values clockwise.
// Keys can be anything you want to use to remember the positions.
$clock = array(
  'a' => 2,
  'b' => 1,
  'c' => 1,
  'd' => 2,
  'e' => 3,
  'f' => 2,
);

$positions = array_keys($clock);
$values = array_values($clock);

// Test all possible starting positions.
for ($i = 0; $i < count($clock); ++$i) {
  $chain = test_clock($values, $i);

  // When the solution has all values, it's the right one.
  if (count($chain) == count($clock)) {
    break;
  }
}

// Use the user-supplied keys.
$solution = array();
foreach ($chain as $position) {
  $solution[] = $positions[$position];
}

print 'The solution is: ' . implode($solution, ' → ') . PHP_EOL;

/**
 * Recursively test the clock based on a supplied position.
 *
 * @param array $values
 *   The current values of the clock.
 * @param integer $i
 *   The current position of the clock.
 * @param array $chain
 *   The current possible solution.
 *
 * @return
 *   An array of positions that represents a possible solution.
 */
function test_clock(array $values, $i, array $chain = array()) {
  // If the value of the position we're in is 0, we've already tested it.
  if ($values[$i] == 0) {
    return $chain;
  }

  // Find the next two positions.
  $position1 = $i + $values[$i];
  $position2 = $i - $values[$i];

  // Account for wraparound in the array.
  if ($position1 > count($values) - 1) {
    $position1 -= count($values);
  }
  if ($position2 < 0) {
    $position2 += count($values);
  }

  // Mark this position as tested.
  $values[$i] = 0;
  $chain[] = $i;

  // Test the first position.
  $solution = test_clock($values, $position1, $chain);

  // Don't bother checking the second position if the first is correct.
  if (count($solution) == count($values)) {
    return $solution;
  }

  // Test the second position.
  return test_clock($values, $position2, $chain);
}
```

Drop that into a file, let's say `hands-of-time.php`, and run it either off of a webserver or via PHP CLI:

```
$ php hands-of-time.php
The solution is: a → e → b → c → d → f
```

Change the `$clock` array to whatever the puzzle is. For example, here's one of the larger clocks:

```
$clock = array(
  'a' => 2,
  'b' => 2,
  'c' => 2,
  'd' => 4,
  'e' => 2,
  'f' => 2,
  'g' => 3,
  'h' => 3,
  'i' => 6,
  'j' => 4,
  'k' => 5,
  'l' => 3,
);
```

And here's the output:

```
The solution is: a → k → f → h → e → g → j → b → d → l → i → c
```

Answer (score 0):

http://nyusuke.com/game/ff13/ff13-2puzzle.html
The clockpuzzle.pl is good as well, but there's a specific puzzle in Oerba (400AF if I remember correctly) that it glitches on. The first link is also (Or at least it was for me) a bit easier to use on the fly. On the clockpuzzle link, I kept forgetting where I was at in the rotation on the couple I tried it for. Nyusuke's is easy to follow regardless of the number of circles.

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the links here have changed into ads (or is unavailable), here's a proper site for solving the Hands of Time puzzles (not affiliated):

https://guides.gamercorner.net/ffxiii-2/hands-of-time/